# Format Pasted content in html editor

Tags: html, tinymce

I am designing a HTML page where i have an editor where users write some text or they can paste some information. But what i need is whenever the data is pasted it should be formatted according to my requirements and should be pasted.

For ex:- we should be able to know that user have pasted this content instead of typing it self. (formatting like left and right indentation, or pasted content in quotes etc..)

I am using tinyMCE but dont know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [the paste plugin](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste). This plugin needs to be configured properly.
have a look [here for the documentation.](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3apaste)

**EDIT:** Example to log the pasted content and to modify the pasted result:

```
    paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
        console.log('Object', o);
        console.log('Content:', o.content);
        o.content = '<span>' + o.content + ' TEST</span>';

   }
```